# Creating new rails migrations error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I've been using the tutorial by Michael Hartl and I am trying to create a new model called "Recipe" to allow users to post recipes. The model is essentially the same as the micropost model, in that a user should be able to post many recipes and all recipes should be linked to one user. I therefore used the same command and migration as for the micropost:

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

Created using the command: rails generate model Micropost content:string user_id:integer

The issue I am having though is that the primary key in both tables is the user_id. Will this work, or when I go to try to enter a recipe will it try to pull from the microposts table instead? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry I should also mention: The code for recipes was entered the same as above: the only difference is that it says "CreateRecipes" instead of "CreateMicroposts at the top, and where it has the create_table method it says recipes instead. The index is the same in both

Answer (score 0):

> when I go to try to enter a recipe will it try to pull from the microposts table instead?

**No.** The `Recipe` model in your application by default will interact with a `recipes` table in your database. Similarly, a `Micropost` model will interact with a `microposts` table in your database by default.

As long as you work with the `Recipe` model, an instance of `Recipe` will not pull from the `microposts` table.

*It sounds like you may have a fundamental misunderstanding about what a table's primary key is for, and perhaps how database tables work; but for now that's outside of the scope of this question.*

---

As an aside, you probably should have done

```
rails generate model MicroPost content:string user_id:integer
```

*(notice the uppercase `P` in `MicroPost`)*. This is a better name for the clase and will create a `micro_posts` table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key is not the user_id in any of the two tables. Each model generates a table with an implicit numeric autoincremented id column that is used as the PK.

What the add_index does is add an index on the user_id column. An index is not a PK.

Anyway, you should change your add_index statement in your recipes migration to:

```
add_index :recipes, [:user_id, :created_at]
```